# Creating a game picking web app in django

Tags: django, database, modelform, formset

I am having issues in writing code for my game picking app, I managed to get a model form working for admin game insertion to database (matchweek, game, result etc) but I am having trouble with writing a form and logic for user picks. I would like user to choose a week (I did this part) and then the form should have all games for that week, user and user picks. The logic is that you get one point for each game guessed right in a week, and than the user with most points gets 25 points for the summary point table. I am trying to get this gamepicking form working with formsets but I am not really sure anymore if my database logic is okay, I have a table called Bet containing user,game_id (FK) ,user pick. I am really stuck on this part.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Share important parts of your code, so you can get help.

Comment: try to read Django Docs. It is really helpful  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/

Comment: Or watch a video tutorial. I suggest Corey Schafer Django set on yooutube